# Scope Error in OOHaskell ExampleProblem

Tags: haskell

I have tried to implement the rectangle problem using OOHaskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls, DeriveDataTypeable, TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fcontext-stack=100 #-}

module Rectangle where

import OOHaskell

$(label "getLength")
$(label "getWidth")
$(label "incr")
$(label "lengthenBy")
$(label "setLength")
$(label "setWidth")

rectangle length width self
          = do
             lengthRef <- newIORef value
              widthRef <- newIORef width
              return $
              getLength   .=. readIORef lengthRef
          .*. getWidth    .=. readIORef widthRef
          .*. setLength   .=. writeIORef lengthRef
          .*. setWidth    .=. writeIORef widthRef
          .*. lengthenBy  .=. (\dv ->
                 do
                   value <- self # getValue
                   (self # setValue) (value + dv))
          .*. incr        .=. (self # (lengthenBy 1))
          .*. emptyRecord
```

But i am getting the scope error. The error meassage is

```
 Rectangle.hs:21:38: Not in scope: `widthRef'
 Rectangle.hs:22:39: Not in scope: `lengthRef'
 Rectangle.hs:23:39: Not in scope: `widthRef'
```

How can i resolve the error?

Thanks Daniel done that. But now the error i am getting is:

```
The function `lengthenBy' is applied to one argument,
but its type `Proxy LengthenBy' has none
In the second argument of `(#)', namely `(lengthenBy 1)'
In the second argument of `(.=.)', namely `(self # (lengthenBy 1))'
In the first argument of `(.*.)', namely
  `incr .=. (self # (lengthenBy 1))'
```

Comment: What is *the rectangle problem*?

Comment: Problem in which there is a simple rectangle and some basic functions that operate on it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your indentation:

```
      = do
         lengthRef <- newIORef value
          widthRef <- newIORef width
```

the 'l' of `lengthRef` and the 'w' of `widthRef` must be in the same column.

As it stands, it is parsed as

```
= do lengthRef <- newIORef value widthRef <- newIORef ...
```

However, I think that should produce a parse error and not reach the 'not in scope' phase. So I guess that's not in your actual code but a paste-glitch here.

Then:

```
          return $
          getLength   .=. readIORef lengthRef
      .*. getWidth    .=. readIORef widthRef
      .*. setLength   .=. writeIORef lengthRef
      .*. setWidth    .=. writeIORef widthRef
      .*. lengthenBy  .=. (\dv ->
             do
               value <- self # getValue
               (self # setValue) (value + dv))
      .*. incr        .=. (self # (lengthenBy 1))
      .*. emptyRecord
```

breaks it, the `.*.` is indented less than the do-block indentation, so it's parsed as

```
(do ...
    getLength .=. readIORef lengthRef) .*. getWidth .=. ...
```

Indent the stuff you want to go inside the `return` farther than the enclosing do-block.

Comment: Never used OOHaskell, so I don't know what everything's type is, but from the error message, a possible cause is that it should be `((self # lengthenBy) 1)` instead of `(self # (lengthenBy 1))`.